# How do you open the search results page from the top right box into a new tab?

Tags: navigation, search-results

I'm pointing to an external site with my top right search navigation (SPNavigation.SearchNav).
I would like this to open up in a new page. Is this possible by using the UI or powershell?

I added `$navnode.properties["Target"] = "_blank"` with no luck.

Comment: Not sure if such property('Target') exist for search nav. You may have to use jQuery to check whether Enter key or Search anchor/button was pressed and use window.open